# Writing to a mounted Windows share

Tags: windows, ubuntu, permissions, network-share

I am using Ubunutu 20.04 and I am trying to write to a mounted Windows share.  This is the command I am using to mount the share:

`sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.5/tv /mnt/tv -o username=xxxxxxxxxx,password=xxxxxxxxx,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777`

I am able to view the contents of the Windows share in Ubuntu:

```
darren@homeserver:~$ ls -l /mnt/tv/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Jun 30 15:33 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Jan  1  2019  MSOCache
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Apr 28 00:38 'Plex dance'
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Dec 30  2019 'System Volume Information'
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Jun 24 15:37 'TV Shows'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  2019  desktop.ini
```

But if I try to create a test file i get this error:

```
 [ Error writing lock file /mnt/tv/.test.swp: Permission denied ]
```

I have the Windows share permissions set to "Everyone":

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
-fstype=cifs,credentials=<fileWithCred>,vers=3.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,noserverino ://<IP-Winshare>/Path
```